# how to inject my main.html to my index.php div by angularjs injector and compile

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-injector

html file at my front end and i need to inject it to my index.php div #container with angularjs injector and compile i'm little new with angular may somebody help ?

at first i tried to do it via ng-include like that

```
<div id="container" ng-include src="'<?= PATH_FRONT_END ?>main.html'"></div>
```

but i need by injector and compile
 something like this 
     angular.injector(['ng']).invoke(['$compile', '$rootScope', function(compile, rootScope){
        var scope = rootScope.$new();
        scope.bar = "ok!";

```
    var result = compile('<div>{{main.html}}</div>')(scope);
    $("#foo").append(result.html());
  }]);
```

but withe a link to my main.html

Comment: not clear what issue is... `ng-include` will automatically be compiled using current scope where it is placed in document, or you can add `ng-controller` to have main.html compile against that controller scope

Comment: also suspect you are trying to use jQuery when you probably shouldn't be....need to see more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need get the html using the $http service. You code should be something like this:

```
$http.get("path/to/your/html/main.html").success(function (response) {
    var result = compile(response)(scope);
    $("#foo").append(result);
})
```